Is there an issue with weighting observations in Bayesian Beta distribution inference?
Let $N_1, N_2, \dots, N_m$ be i.i.d. with $N_i \sim \textrm{Geometric}(p)$, so $\mathbb{P}(N_i = n) = p(1-p)^{n-1}$ for $n\in\{1, 2, \dots\}$.
Let $X_1, \dots, X_m$ be independent and distributed with $X_i \sim \textrm{Binomial}(N_i, \theta)$.
If I have a $\textrm{Beta}(\alpha_0, \beta_0)$ prior for $\theta$, then $$p(\theta \mid N, X) \sim \textrm{Beta}\left(\alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m X_i, \beta_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m (N_i - X_i)\right).$$
Suppose that I'm interested in weighting the inference so that each of the $m$ observations has equal weight in the inference. This is for two reasons: it makes the approach naturally robust to outliers; and in many applications I'm interested in how an intervention will affect the 'typical' user with a low $N_i$, rather than the users with large $N_i$. A user with a spurious and large $N_i$ value would dominate the posterior using the formula above.
Is there an issue with making the $m$ observations have equal weight in the posterior by replacing it with
$$p(\theta \mid N, X) \sim \textrm{Beta}\left(\alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{X_i}{N_i}, \beta_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{N_i - X_i}{N_i}\right),\tag{$\star$}\label{eq}$$
so we use the proportions of success for each of the $m$ observations instead of the total number?
The above formula was my intuition but it also matches the approach in Weighted likelihood in Bayesian inference by Claudio Agostinelli and Luca Greco with including weights to make a pseudo-likelihood function. Specifically they replace the likelihood
$$L(x \mid \theta) \propto \prod_{i=1}^m \theta^{x_i}(1 - \theta)^{n_i - x_i}$$
with
$$\prod_{i=1}^m \left[\theta^{x_i}(1 - \theta)^{n_i - x_i}\right]^{w(x_i, n_i)},$$
and if I set $w(x_i, n_i) = n_i^{-1}$ then I the pseudo-posterior distribution of $\theta$ would be \eqref{eq}.
Another alternative that I've considered is using a separate $\theta_i$ for each observation: $X_i \sim \textrm{Binom}(N_i, \theta_i)$, where $\theta_i \sim \textrm{Beta}(\gamma, \delta)$ and then making inference about the hyper distribution that is generating the $p_i$. But this seems unnecessarily complicated compared to the first approach.
Is the only loss here the fact that I'm essentially throwing away some information by down-weighting some of the observations? Is there another straightforward way to make each of the $m$ observations equally important in the final inference?

Am I correct that the $p_i$'s refer to a different quantity than the Geometric $p$? If so, maybe $\theta_i$ is a better notation?

Thank you for the correction @ZackFisher, let me change that

My a few points:

To me, the choice of a likelihood model is better judged by its performance in fitting the data, rather than by its behavior in the posterior. Weighting the likelihood seems a quick proxy to a different data generating model. So the question becomes which one better describes the observed data, or better predicts new data.

I don't think weighting necessarily throws away some information. It just says some observations are relatively more important than others.

If a method is good, it should be good whether or not a specific prior is used, i.e., having both frequentist and Bayesian interpretations. By allowing $\theta_i$ to be different across observations, the data model itself is a hierarchical one. So the inference focus becomes $\gamma$ and $\delta$, which seems serving a different purpose than focusing inference on $\theta$. But again, I would judge it by goodness of fit, since this is a different data model, rather than a different prior.

Lastly, if one believes the current data generating model is satisfactory, a joint (dependent) prior for $(p,\theta)$ could also be considered, where the $(1-p)^{n_i}$ component will be a contributing factor when integrating $p$ out of the joint posterior of $(p,\theta)$, making the marginal posterior of $\theta$ differently affected by $n_i$ in some way.




Completely agree, and I am hopeful that this weighting will make it more useful for predicting future data. Testing this method vs another on their predictive ability is definitely a good idea for assessing which to use.



If I was happy to use the standard method then I would have narrower estimation and prediction intervals for $\theta$, so if there was no problem with the data from large $N_i$ it would be throwing data away. But yes, I agree, in my situation it's not throwing data away but reweighting it.



Yep, agreed. To me it seems doubtful that I will gain much predictive gain for my effort in using the hierarchical model, but if the (*) formula doesn't fit the data well then the hierarchical one may do better



I'm assuming you mean "unsatisfactory" instead of "satisfactory"? Yes, this is also a great idea, I will also try this one if the predictions from (*) need improving. Thank you for your answer


@Alex Thanks. For point 4, I'm trying to separate the "data model" with the "prior". So if the data model is satisfactory but the resulting inference has some unsatisfactory feature, then changing to the different prior would be a choice (without changing the data model).
